# Install Jupyter Notebooks without installing anaconda navigator

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

I need to install Jupyter Notebook but I do not want to have to install anaconda navigator with it.

Is there anyway that I can install Jupyter Notebooks without installing Anaconda.

Comment: https://jupyter.org/install

Comment: I'm not sure the edit is necesssary, `pip` is a CMD command

Answer (score 0):

Go to your terminal and use the pip tool.

```
pip install notebook
```

source: [Jupyter Installation](https://jupyter.org/install)

If you haven't tried JupyterLab, I'd recommend it, which provides a better Notebook experience than the traditional one.

Comment: I have tried that method already and I have followed the instructions on jupyter.org/install, but when i try to run it says it says that jupyter is not recgonized as a command

Comment: @BilawalAsghar then you need to provide more detailed information about your system and the commands you execute before and after trying to install jupyter